# Is "drin" in "Es ist noch mehr drin" an idiom?

Tags: grammar, idiom

In my dictionary, *drin* is an idiomatic component of both *drin sein* (to be into it), and *das ist doch nicht drin* (that's not on).

But I'm not sure which of these meanings go into this newspapers title:

> [Es ist noch mehr drin](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/bundestagswahl-2013/wahlkampf-es-ist-noch-mehr-drin-12290040.html).

Any suggestions?

Comment: It basically means: "There is room for improvement." "drin" here just means something like "inside" and the sentence would literally be "There is something left inside". And that is exactly what it means: "There is some potential inside left unused, which should be put to use." It often goes with: "Da können wir noch mehr rausholen."

Comment: *A better result is possible*, or *it's not yet all that can be gotten out of the situation*, or *you can afford more in the situation*. Or Simply: *More is possible*.

Comment: @bouscher: there is nothing wrong with having more than one answer to a question. In fact we should watch our answers/question ratio which dropped close to the limit of 2.5 for ["Excellent" in Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage).

Comment: @Takkat Well, I'm not addressing the question, which was about two versions of idiomatic meaning. I'm just clearing up the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate this idiomatically as

> It's not the end of it.

Translating it more or less literally, it means "It's not empty yet" (to be precise: "It contains more.")

Answer (score 1):

Drin (or darin) literally means "inside that" but is also often the translation for just inside.
So

> drin sein

means

> to be inside

and this is used in all kinds of expressions both abstract or literal, two of which you mentioned. The headline just uses the same abstract idea like the second of your examples... think of it this way: you have a bag out of which you take "life". If something is not inside, that means you can't do it. If there is more drin that means you can do more.

Comment: Should we say somewhere that *"drin sein"* is colloquial?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is... in a novel this could be written: "Draussen trieb eisiger Wind dicke Schneeflocken über das Feld, drin aber war es warm."... "darin" wouldn't work here, neither would "innen". So I think at least in some cases "drin" is the best option hence not always colloquial

Comment: I would expect _drinnen_ in the novel, not _drin_.

Comment: "drin" is colloquial, I'ld say. I would not expect to read it in formal texts (e.g. in a book outside of written dialogue, or in a serious newspaper).

Comment: @adhominen: http://www.faz.net/suche/?query=drin&resultsPerPage=20&suchbegriffImage.x=0&suchbegriffImage.y=0    although many of the examples are "mehr drin sein" there are still others in the FAZ. IMHO the term colloquial is used too much.It should be reserved to things that are really only spoken and put in "..." if in writing... that's just me though